# How to run native commands on self-hosted Github Runner?

Tags: git, github

Basically, I am trying to run a native command with **deploy.yml** file on a self-hosted Github Runner. But the problem is, even though the runner is self-hosted it is unable to find the commands on the host.

Here is the code:

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: "pnpm"
      - run: pnpm i
      - run: pm2 restart backend_api
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
.../_work/_temp/3a690aa0-40c1-4a01-8763-3fae7b2fc7bd.sh: line 1: pm2: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

I don't want to install pm2 on the deploy.yml, as that would be a seperate pm2 instance. I want the deploy.yml get the installed pm2 on the host and run it. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a hook that will trigger once an action is finished?

Comment: What do you mean by "native commands". Do you mean bash? Or powershell? Or something else?